# OBD2 BLE communication from iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, obd-ii

I will be using OBD2 device to get data form a car. I don't have the dongle yet, but am reading into how things should be done. As far as I understand the device should be with BLE on and should scan for peripherals with some specific service.

For example I need to get the speed of the vehicle. How should I know what is the UUID of the service I am looking for and what are the UUIDs of its characteristics and possibly some details about the data that should be received. For devices using GATT profiles for example they could be found here: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services . But I don't find any such documentation for OBD2. I found this answer: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52075456/which-gatt-profile-and-services-are-used-by-obd-ble-adapters-like-lelink-automa/52139765#52139765) and the first one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44720593/trouble-reading-data-from-obd-2). As far as I understand they suggest I need to look through all peripherals and all services there and try all characteristics to find the needed ones and distinguish them by the response. Is this the only way to do this? I found also this project: [here](https://github.com/msedd/DP003-OBD2_BluetoothLE_iOS/blob/master/iOS/ConnectMyCar/ConnectMyCar/BLEController.m) where some UUID is used but I cannot understand where it comes from. Any suggestions how to get the needed UUID-s?

Comment: _How should I know what is the UUID of the service I am looking for and what are the UUIDs of its characteristics and possibly some details about the data that should be received_ - shouldn't that information be in your device's documentation?

Comment: @mag_zbc Thanks for your response. I don't have the dongle yet, so I guess it is possible, but I thought they were the same for all OBD2 dongles because I think it should be possible for a device to scan for such services without having the exact UUID for every different dongle. But I may be misunderstanding it.

Comment: If the manufacturers say you need to read/wirte from a special characteristic they will provide the UDID for that characteristic. If there is no such UDID you can check (when you have the dongle) the characteristic properties (if it's read & write, if it's write & notify..etc) based on these properties you can figure some of the right charactersitics but this is not as good as the manufacturer specs.

Comment: @danypata Thanks. So I guess I am waiting for the dongle.

Comment: I gave an answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52075456/which-gatt-profile-and-services-are-used-by-obd-ble-adapters-like-lelink-automa